# Sqlite failing to correctly compare decimal numbers

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I've having a weird problem where comparisons on a numeric column doesn't give the correct results. The input is the same, but if the coalesce() function is applied, suddenly no rows match.

The table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
    orderid        INT NOT NULL,
    freight        NUMERIC,
    PRIMARY KEY (orderid),
);
```

I'm testing the query with this method:

```
private void Problematic(IDbConnection connection)
{
    using (var cmd = session.Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText =
            @"select order0_.OrderId as OrderId55_,
                     order0_.Freight as Freight55_,
              from
                    Orders order0_
              where
                    coalesce(order0_.Freight, @p0) > @p1";  // ALT 1
                 // order0_.Freight > @p1";                 // ALT 2

        var p0 = cmd.CreateParameter();
        p0.ParameterName = "p0";
        p0.DbType = DbType.Decimal;
        p0.Value = 100;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p0);

        var p1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
        p1.ParameterName = "p1";
        p1.DbType = DbType.Decimal;
        p1.Value = 0;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // ALT 1 above yields 0 result rows.
            // ALT 2 above yields 830 result rows.
        }
    }
}
```

The `Freight` column is nullable, but all actual values are non-null and greater than 0. Therefore I expect the two queries to generate the same number of matching rows.

I'm analysing the types with this query:

```
select
    typeof(@p0),
    typeof(@p1),
    typeof(coalesce(order0_.Freight, @p0)),
    typeof(order0_.Freight),
    coalesce(order0_.Freight, @p0) > @p1,
    order0_.Freight > @p1
from
    Orders order0_
```

The result (for all rows) is:

```
    typeof(@p0)                              => text
    typeof(@p1)                              => text 
    typeof(coalesce(order0_.Freight, @p0))   => real
    typeof(order0_.Freight)                  => real
    coalesce(order0_.Freight, @p0) > @p1     => 0
    order0_.Freight > @p1                    => 1
```

**Can anyone explain why the different expressions generate different results?**

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you also use `ifnull`? I.e., `ifnull(order0_.Freight, @p0) > @p1`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your database driver converts `DBType.Decimal` to text.

Use `DBType.Double` instead.